# jQuery Date picker - Set current date

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

**javaScript**

```
<script>
$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
    minDate: "today",
    maxDate: "+30d",
    setDate: "+1d"
  });
});
</script>
```

**The response :**

[image]

**The response expected with current date selected :**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setDate` is your friend.  `"setDate", "0"` is todays date. You can increase and decrease number as per needed.

`$("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", "1");`

Example:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
    minDate: "today",
    maxDate: "+30d",
  });
  $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", "1");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0-rc.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```